# Scraping websites with BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

### I have this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = requests.get("http://www.cvbankas.lt/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

urls = []
for article_tag in soup.find_all("article"):
        a_tag = article_tag.find('a')
        urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])
        div_tag = article_tag.find('span')
        urls.append(div_tag.attrs['class'])

print(urls)
```

---

Can anyone explane me how to get the data marked in red?

[image: Webpage source screenshot]

Comment: Have you had a look at the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? You're using `find_all` to find URLs at the moment, but you could use it to `find_all(class_="salary_amount")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get span with the class label "salary_amount"

```
salary_object = article_tag.find("span", class_= "salary_amount")
```

and then extract the text with the .text attribute of the created object.